# Do we need separate Pokemon tags for the same region/generation games?

Tags: discussion, tags, pokemon

What I mean, for example, is do we need separate [heart-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-gold) and [soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul-silver) tags?

I'm thinking of what kinds of questions are possible. The majority will be independent of what version is being played. Any questions about exclusivity features are much better served by an answer that covers both versions - knowing what is available or not in one version is the opposite of what is available or not in the other version. So they'll always be packed together, for the most part.

What are your thoughts? Do we really need to consume 3 tags on these?

Comment: Related: [On dungeons](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1506/how-should-we-tag-the-pokemon-mystery-dungeon-series)

Answer (score 5):

95% of questions will not be specific to any individual game in a generation.

The other 5% however will:

- How do I catch Ho-Oh/Lugia (the prerequisites depend on the game)
- Where is the Batte Frontier in Sinnoh? (Diamond/Pearl: Nowhere. Platinum: In the battle zone)
- How do I catch Kyogre in Hoenn? (Ruby: You can't. Sapphire: Through the plot. Emerald: Appears afterwards)

However, people's instinct will be to tag it with the version they are playing. So most people will tag it with [heart-gold] when [johto-gen-4] (or whatever tag is decided) is more appropriate.

I don't think there is much we can do about this, short of retagging questions after the fact. That 5% of unique questions means we can't just make them tag synonyms.

Comment: Actually, the major opponent to tag synonyms is that I wouldn't want to add [black] or [white] as having to be Pokemon. But my thought pattern is, for your examples, why does it need to be tagged separately? Your answers you gave can fit perfectly in one answer to one question - we don't need to actually separate it into separate questions on the different versions.

Comment: Because people won't give an all in one answer - they'll give an answer for the version the question asker mentions. Then it'll be accepted.

Comment: So someone will come along later, see that the question is tagged sinnoh-4th-gen, asking about the Battle Frontier. "Oh, that applies to me." Read the question, go to the battle zone, and wonder where it is. They'll head back, and ask the same question, getting a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we need Heart-Gold and Soul-Silver tags as long as we have a way to differentiate between the different releases within a generation. Pearl / Platinum / Diamond are also 4th-gen, but the question applies to something specific to the former, not the latter. There's nothing *wrong* about tagging it 4th-gen, but since its a sub-category within that tag, it needs (I think) more differentiation

I think this can be achieved by creating region tags, rather than for the individual brands. In this case, 4th-gen and sinnoh vs. 4th-gen and johto.

Admittedly, folks are probably going to want to tag the name of the game in anyway, as they are more recognized than the names of the various regions.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the tags are unnecessary, but of course the question title and content of the question should explain which game they need to know the information for. Also, I don't think `pokemon-third-gen` and `pokemon-fourth-gen` are necessary either, (but that's just my opinion).

Comment: There are some pretty drastic changes for recurring elements (e.g. battle frontier) between Pokemon Emerald, and Pokemon SoulSilver for example.

Comment: True, but I don't think it's necessary to create a tag for them; IMO the information should just be in the question. Then again, I'm not too familiar with the mechanics of the SE sites so maybe having the tags would be easier to search/sort?